# Spring JPA delete entity not working when iterating

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to delete an entity using its remove method of its repository from another service class, but it is not getting deleted. Below code works when I hard code the Id:

```
long id = 1234;
Optional<Employee> employeeOptional = employeeRepository.findById(id);
Employee employee = employeeOptional.get();
employeeRepository.delete(employee);
```

Above code is working fine, but if I try with below code, deletion is not happening.

```
for (Employee employee : department.getEmployees()) {
     if (employee.getRole().equals("Manager")) {
        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
     }
}
```

I am trying the code from DepartmentServiceImpl class, but above is not working, but same when id is hardcoded it works.

Inside Department I have relationship like below,

```
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "deal")
  private Set<Employee> employees= new HashSet<>();
```

And inside Employee I have like below,

```
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "department_id", referencedColumnName = "department_id")
  private Department department;
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.

Comment: (Downvoted, since similar edits have been made on your material in the past).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to delete Employees, but your entities still have references to each other.

A better way to delete an employee is to use orphan removal and remove the employee from the collection which will trigger a delete.

Also **mappedBy = "deal"** should be the name of the attribute on the owning side of the relationship so this should be **mappedBy = "department"**

```
@OneToMany(
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    mappedBy = "department",
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private Set<Employee> employees= new HashSet<>();
```

add a method to Department to remove the Employee and keep the bidirectional relationship in sync by also removing Department from Employee

```
public void removeEmployee(Employee employee) {
    employees.removeEmployee(employee);
    employee.setDepartment(null);
}
```

you can then remove the 'Managers' from your Employees collection which should trigger the delete statements

```
List<Employee> managers = department.getEmployees.stream()
                .filter(e -> e.getRole().equals("Manager"))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

for (Employee manager : managers) {
    department.removeEmployee(manager);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but should work fine:
Try tweaking your code a little like this:

```
Set<Employee>employees= new HashSet<>();
for (Employee employee : department.getEmployees()) {
     if (employee.getRole().equals("Manager")) {
        employees.add(employee);
     }
}

department.setEmployees(employees);//I assume you have a setter
departmentRepository.save(department); //I hope you understand what departmentRepository means
```

Here you are reassigning the valid employees list.
You could follow another method, instead of deleting each entity separately, you could call a bulk-save using `saveAll`(...) method on the valid list.